# EJB 2.0 and 3.0 life cycle

Tags: ejb

Respected EJB Expert,

I am writing this email after lot of R&D. Recently I attended an interview wherea I was asked for EJB event cycle in terms of method invocation. I told them exactly whatever is mentioned at internet. But the interviewer was very dangerously expert. He asked me which component calls which method. Eg. who created the EJB home object and EJB Object.. I answered him with the info what I had... but then he confused me a lot especially by asking me who invokes the above methods in EJB 3.0. Basically he wanted me to tell the complete cycle starting from the client's JNDI lookup till client getting the response of the EJB method. He also wanted to know the enviornment in which the method or event occurs and who invokes the method or event.

I will be very thankful to you if can provide me with your inputs in the below format for all EJBs for 2.0 and 3.0 version

Environment ## Method-name or Event ## Method or Event Invoker

Comment: Try to explain better this: Environment ## Method-name or Event ## Method or Event Invoker

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is that the EJB container itself is responsible for creating the EJB home implementation, instantiating the EJB object instances, and invoking all lifecycle methods on the EJB object instance.

For EJB 2.x, the client looks up a reference to a home from JNDI, and the container provides an object that implements the home interface.  The container home object responds to the create method by returning another container proxy object that implements the component interface, which allows it to implement all the EJB qualities of service (transaction, security, java:comp, etc.) before delegating the actual bean instance that it creates.

For EJB 3.x, the situation is similar, except the container proxy object that implements the business interface is either injected directly or looked up directly from JNDI because the home interface is no longer required.